# Differing factors for $f(x) = x^4+x^2+1$

Tags: polynomials

$$f(x)=x^4+x^2+1$$

$\implies f(x)= (x^2)^2+x^2+1=(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}+1 =(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$

$\implies f(x) = (x^2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2})(x^2+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2})$

But we also have:

$f(x) = (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$

Both of these factorisations satisfy $f(x)=f(-x)$, and expanding them again yields the original expression. So I was computing this to determine if $x^4+x^2+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Why are there two different factorisations?

Comment: One of the factorizations you have given is not done over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The quartic has $4$ roots in $\mathbb{C}\,$. The two factorizations combine them into different pairs. As a side note, the roots are in fact the complex $6^{th}$ roots of unity since $x^6-1=(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)\,$.

Comment: @Batominovski Yes I know, but suppose we're dealing instead with $f(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, then why are the two factorisations different? Or is this normal?

Comment: @mrnovice All polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ factor into *linear* factors over $\mathbb{C}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Oh okay, that makes sense then thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't actually different factorizations. Notice that when we can factor the product
$$(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
further to get
$$(x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i)(x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i)(x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i)(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i)$$

Comment: I understand now, was having a brain fart for some reason, thanks